# Java For Loop with Array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I made a 2d array, and need to map the elements `[i][j] = 0,1,2,3,4,` or `5` to colored pixels to be printed. This is what I have.

The array of pixels, integer value representing a different color

```
    static int [][] marioArray = new int [][]{
    {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,2,2,2,3,3,4,3,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,2,3,2,3,3,3,4,3,3,3,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,3,3,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,1,1,5,1,1,5,1,1,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,1,1,5,1,1,5,1,1,1,0,0,0},
    {0,0,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1,0,0},
    {0,0,3,3,1,5,3,5,5,3,5,1,3,3,0,0},
    {0,0,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,0,0},
    {0,0,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,5,5,5,0,0,5,5,5,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0},
    {0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0}};
```

The method to print a pixel

```
public static void drawPixl (Graphics g, int x, int y, int scale, Color color)
{
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(x,y,scale,scale);
}
```

My attempt at a for loop with my array

```
    public static void drawMario (Graphics g, int x, int y, int scale)
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0, i < 16, i++){
            int j;
            for(j = 0, j <16, j++){
            if (marioArray[i][j] == 1){
                drawPixl(g,scale*i,scale*j,scale,Color.red);}
            if (marioArray[i][j] == 2){
                drawPixl(g,scale*i,scale*j,scale,new Color(94, 38, 18));}
            if (marioArray[i][j] == 3){
                drawPixl(g,scale*i,scale*j,scale,new Color(255, 193, 37));}
            if (marioArray[i][j] == 4){
                drawPixl(g,scale*i,scale*j,scale,Color.black);}
            if (marioArray[i][j] == 5){
                drawPixl(g,scale*i,scale*j,scale,Color.blue);}
            else;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried a nested for loop, an enhanced for loop, and a while loop, but I'm not having any luck I guess

**Edit:**

I tested the `drawPixl()` and it works fine. The only errors pop up next to each of the for loops in `drawMario`, where it states:

```
 1. Syntax error on token '<', ( expected

 2. Syntax error, insert ';;) Statement' to complete ForStatement

 3. the method i(int, int) is undefined for the type Animation
```

Also, int scale is used both to locate where the pixel should be and to give it the right size

Comment: It might help people to understand your question better if you add information about the output or errors you get.

Answer (score 2):

Use semicolon in the `for` loop:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j <16; j++){
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void drawMario (Graphics g, int x, int y, int scale)
{
    int i;
    //for(i = 0, i < 16, i++){  --> HERE IS THE ERROR, YOU NEED TO ADD ; AFTER  0 AND 16
      for(i = 0; i < 16; i++){ // --> AFTER ADDING ;
        int j;
        //for(j = 0, j <16, j++){  --> HERE IS THE ERROR, YOU NEED TO ADD ; AFTER 0 AND 16
          for(j = 0; j <16; j++){ // --> AFTER ADDING ;
        if (marioArray[i][j] == 1){
            drawPixl(g,scale*i,scale*j,scale,Color.red);}
        if (marioArray[i][j] == 2){
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with more dynamic approach. Here you will never get AOB exception, and you don't have to change loop parameters when input array size changes.

```
for(int i = 0; i < marioArray.length; i++){
    int [] row = marioArray[i];
    for(int j = 0; j <row.length; j++){
        Color color = null;
        switch(row[j]){
            case 1:
               color = Color.red; break;
            case 2: 
               color = Color(94, 38, 18); break;
              ...
         }
         if(color!=null){
           drawPixl(g,scale*i,scale*j,scale,color);
         }
  }
}
```

Your code will be cleaner, in switch statement you will only choose `Color`, so you don't have to copy whole `drawPixl` method to every row.

In Java you don't have to declare loop index outside of an loop,, unless you need it somehow outside of a loop.